# Browser for Developers no cache

Tags: caching, browser

Does anyone know of a good browser or plugin for developers that doesnt cache anything? Every time im developing a web app, even if i clear my cache and history some saved data persists. I end up having to run c cleaner every 5 minutes to wipe everything. Its quite annoying, and probably bad for my computer, and my sanity, and society.

Comment: Chrome - F12 -> Settings -> (General) Disable Cache

Comment: Using CCleaner for clearing browser caches seems pretty overkill.

Comment: you'd think Chrome - F12 -> Settings -> (General) Disable Cache would work, but i have that on all the time and some data still persists.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Chrome from the menu on right when you click on it there is option called `New incognito window` using this you 'll have browser with no Cache, it 'll be more like you are a spy and don't want to get caught by anything.

In ff you can get the same by -- File==>`New private window`